# Totally new kernel on OpenWRT

Tags: kernel, openwrt

Is there any possibility to install totally new kernel on OpenWRT? Currently I have 3.18 version, but I have to downgrade to patched kernel by Candela Tech to install new firmware for ath10k. I have been searching in google how to bite this, but there is no fine instruction how to do that.

**Update:** (copied from answer of TS)

Nam Pham...

I tried to do as you instructed me, but there occured one problem

```
Applying patch platform/310-lib-add-rle-decompression.patch
patching file lib/Kconfig
Hunk #1 succeeded at 227 with fuzz 2 (offset -6 lines).
patching file lib/Makefile
Hunk #1 FAILED at 97.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- rejects in file lib/Makefile
patching file include/linux/rle.h
patching file lib/rle.c
Patch platform/310-lib-add-rle-decompression.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)
make[3]: *** [sdk2/build_dir/target mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/linux-ar71xx_generic/linux-3.17/.quilt_checked] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `sdk2/target/linux/ar71xx'
make[2]: *** [compile] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `sdk2/target/linux'
make[1]: *** [target/linux/compile] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `sdk2'
make: *** [target/linux/compile] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not wrong ,your question is how to change the kernel version in OpenWRT.

Let's say I'm using

```
OpenWRT: CC 15.05
Target system: Atheros AR7xxx/AR9xxx
```

The current version of kernel is 3.18 and I want to downgrade to 3.17

There are 2 folders you need to care :

```
openwrt/target/linux/generic
openwrt/target/linux/ar71xx
```

Step1.Edit the Makefile in  *openwrt/target/linux/ar71xx/Makefile*

```
- KERNEL_PATCHVER:=3.18
+ KERNEL_PATCHVER:=3.17
```

Step2.Create the configuration files for your kernel

```
openwrt/target/linux/generic/config-3.17
openwrt/target/linux/ar71xx/config-3.17
```

I suggest you just copy the *config-3.18* to *config-3.17*. You can modify them later by

```
cd openwrt
make kernel_menuconfig
```

Step3.Try to compile it:

```
cd openwrt
make target/linux/clean
make target/linux/compile V=s
```

For the first time,the kernel source code *linux-3.17.tar.xz* will be downloaded into *openwrt/dl*.
Then it's uncompressed and compiled without any patches.

Step4. Create folder *patches-3.17* then put your own kernel patches (from Candela Tech) in it.

`openwrt/target/linux/ar71xx/patches-3.17`

Repeat with Step3.

To make a patch file in OpenWRT ,you can take a look on this link
https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/patches

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you scroll down to my latest post? :)

Comment: I must have 50 reputation to comment to your latest post. :)).So I answer here.
The issue is : you are using the patch file *310-lib-add-rle-decompression.patch* from Kernel 3.18 to Kernel 3.17

Comment: But this patch is automatically downloaded. I don't do anything with this file. I totally deleted kernel directory and "make" downloaded while folder again.

Comment: Yes it is. Should I delete it to make it download for itself??

Comment: Could you remove this comment with "/home/jacek/Desktop/xxx/sdk2/target/linux/ar71xx/patches-3.17"? I forgot to change directory names :)

I think that the main problem is that I have to download patches to 3.17. But basic openwrt_sdk downloaded from git has patches for 3.18. I can't find those patches.

Comment: Is this command `make target/linux/{clean,prepare} V=s QUILT=1` adjust patches to specific kernel version?

Comment: No , the command won't adjust patches for specific kernel.There aren't any patches for kernel 3.17 from OpenWrt_sdk(CC 15.05). There are patches-3.18 for current version and patches-3.13 for older version . But I think you don't need to apply all the patches , you can create your own patches-3.17 based on what you want to do with kernel 3.17

Comment: If `make target/linux/compile V=s` returned `make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'compile'.` what should I do next?

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with your Makefile in /target/linux.
If you have tried  "target/linux/clean" but it didn't work .Then you should do this:
cd sdk2 ; rm -rf  tmp ; make clean ; make V=s

Comment: I made `make V=s -j1`, but another f@#$%& occured... http://pastebin.com/siJRC9wq. I think that the problem is with those incompatible patches, but `make target/linux/compile` went well.

Comment: Do you know answer and you forgot to reply? :) Because I can't go on, due to this problem. I am sitting and trying all methods to repair this, but none of them works. I tried to download new packages, eg. `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.19.0-65`. Even I wanted to modify some files, but every time I `make`, the main linux folder is reextracted. :/

Comment: hi jaceks, I tried my best to help. Now you know how difficult it is to work with kernel.give me some time (:

Comment: In "make menuconfig" what are your "Target System" and "Target Profile"  ?

Comment: `Target System (Atheros AR7xxx/AR9xxx)`
`Target Profile (TP-LINK Archer C5/C7)`

Comment: Man,I spent a day to check and create patches for 3.17 (: .Here it the link:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Apjnb0PUMcemhIgdS7_hdkVRv4SYzg

This is not yet done.
.It has error with "make target/install"

Comment: Once everything compiles correctly, how do you actually install the new kernel you just built? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in case someone finds this page for changing openwrt kernel, here is what I figured out based on this page info, thanks again!

Here I'm taking changing kernel 5.10 to kernel 5.16 for example for x86 platform:

1. update this file kernel info from 5.10.x -> 5.16.y:
   target/linux/x86/Makefile
2. create this file: include/kernel-5.16
   and its hash value is based on this calculating:
   ${openwrt_topdir}/staging_dir/host/bin/mkhash sha256 linux-5.10.92.tar.xz
3. create this file: target/linux/generic/config-5.16
   if not sure, just #cp config-5.10 config-5.16
4. create confg-5.16 file under target/linux/x86/ this dir and subdirectory which have config-5.10

with these changes, I successfully build the 5.16 kernel in openwrt.

Answer (score 0):

Using openwrt master branch and then building for your device should give you a new kernel. Last time I checked it was 4.1 I guess.

Comment: You misunderstood my problem